# how to test the Geo location identifier feature?

Tags: php, javascript, api, geolocation, geoip

I have jut implemented the GEO location identifier using the GEO IP API?... could you please suggest how to test this feature... i am in new york... when i open up the site, its showing me th New York... But i don't know how to check for other cities... Please suggest.

Comment: Just to confirm - which GEO IP API are you using?  The [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) one?  {The best way to test is to find open proxies that specify their location and visit the page from there... but you can never be certain their reporting correctly}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to test other locations with a proxy service.

Answer (score 1):

The **second parameter** for `getCurrentPosition()` is a **callback for the failure** case. In the third parameter you can set for how many seconds the browser should wait for a response (in my example 5 sec) and how long the result should be cached (in my example 1 h).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    alert('Success');
}, function() {
    alert('Fail!!!');
}, {maximumAge:60000, timeout: 5000});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using proxy server or for testing purpose can try to hardcode ip's of different geographical locations in your application. For list of public proxies, check the below link.
http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/1